# React Hooks at the top level of a multi page form built with react-hook-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I'm trying to use a react-hook-form which is a multi step form and where one of the steps has a conditional `form field`.

The condition on the field is that a `boolean` attribute is true. If it is true, I want to display a set of questions relating to that attribute.

I have found this [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-fom-unregister-controlled-component-hu990), and I have tried to follow the logic of it in my attempt, which is set out below:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import useForm from "react-hook-form";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { useStateMachine } from "little-state-machine";
import updateAction from "./updateAction";




const Techniques = props => {
  const { register, unregister, handleSubmit, setValue, watch, errors } = useForm();
  const { action } = useStateMachine(updateAction);
  const onSubit = data => {
    action(data);
    props.history.push("./ProposalInnovation");
  };

const fundingOffer = watch("fundingOffer");

const CustomInput = React.memo(({ register, unregister, setValue, fundingOffer }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    register({ fundingOffer });

    return () => unregister(fundingOffer);
  }, [fundingOffer, register, unregister]);
  return <input onChange={e => setValue(fundingOffer, e.target.value)} />;
});

function App() {
  const { register, unregister, handleSubmit, setValue, watch } = useForm();
  const fundingOffer = watch("fundingOffer");


  return (

    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubit)}>

        <label>Test for condition:</label>
        <radio 
          ref={register} 
          name="fundingOffer"

        />

        <label>Conditional Field:</label>
        {fundingOffer == true && (
          <CustomInput {...{ register, unregister, setValue, fundingOffer: false }} />
        )}



        <input type="submit" value="next" />    




      </form>

    </div>  
  );
};
};

export default withRouter(Techniques);
```

When I try this in my code, I get an error that says:

React Hook `useEffect` cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function

I think the problem is that I have used the hook inside the multi step form - so maybe that counts as not being at the top level (when I'm a few steps into my multi step form).

Does anyone know how to use conditional logic in hooks in this form construct?

Comment: you showing all the code ? because it's looks good

Comment: What is Techniques exactly? It seems like its missing to return some html and its missing a closing }. Im also very ocnfused on why you have your App component in here and only export the Techniques Component by default with the router. The whole structure of those componnets seem to be incomplete and very confusing. Can you share a codePen or CodeSandbox?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend build pages into multiple routes and with each page submit your data into a local store: `redux`, `mobx`, `little-state-machine` and ect... at last you can submit all your data into a service.

**your routes:**

```
<Routes>
  <Page1 />
  <Page2 />
</Routes>
```

**your individual page:**

```
const Page1 = (props) => {
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    // update your data into your store
    props.history.push('/page2')    
  }

  return <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
    <input name="data" ref={register} />
   </form>
}
```

As reference you can refer to our documentation website as well:

https://react-hook-form.com/advanced-usage#WizardFormFunnel

Comment: I was trying your wizard example from the link above, and the navigation between steps does not work WITH React 18.x; By not work I mean the Url changes in the Browser but the page not not refresh, e.g. /step2 route still shows Step-1 Page; I suspect this is because React.18 does not unmount and re-mount the components; Thus, it would be helpful if your doco stated what versions of react-router and react they apply to, instead of letting dummies like me be stuck and wondering why the examples do not work :-)